# How to give access to a specific group people on newly created custom page in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I have created a new custom page in alfresco and i want to give access that particular page for a particular group only. If there is any way please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where you are accessing that new page? Is it from menu ? Is It from document library?

Comment: @SanjayPatel thanks for the reply.....    its from Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be by using an evaluator on the Share module that contains your custom page, see https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-extensions-share-module-deployment.html

Your evaluator can check to see whether the user is in the appropriate group and then hide the module, if not, thus hiding the page.